# @FocusState not working at all on Xcode14 running iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode14

I am unable to make this work as intended, I wrote this simple code in Xcode 14 beta, I'm trying to focus the TextField using a Button. No results...

XCODE Version 14.0 beta 5 (14A5294e)

```
@FocusState private var isTexting: Bool
@State private var text: String = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        TextField("00000000", text: $text)
            .focused($isTexting)
        Button {
            isTexting = true
        } label: {
            Text("start texting")
        }

    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}
```

[DEMO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nde3k.gif)

Comment: Worked perfectly here in both Xcode beta and non-beta Xcode. No error.

Comment: which version of beta?

Comment: Version 14.0 beta 5 (14A5294e)

Comment: Updated. Works fine here. Xcode 14b5 / iOS16

Comment: Same issue here... I'm using Xcode 14